# Ubuntu 14.04 software installation problems

Tags: ubuntu, installation, dependencies, deb

I'm trying to install latest Warzone 2100 from Ubuntu Software Center, but can't due to dependencies (see image).

[image: Installation error for Warzone2100]

I downloaded deb file to install manually, but I either get the same errors or have the following problems:

1. Where should I put a `.deb` file to make it visible for `apt-get` command? Desktop seems to be out of scan
2. How do I write a correct path in the terminal? There are so many articles where they say to use `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file`, but no real example. How do I begin that path, with which folder? I tried `/home/etc`, `home/etc`, `/desktop/etc`, `desktop/etc`, but nope. Any real example?
3. How do I move `.deb` file to `/var/cache/apt/archives/` folder? I can't move anything to and from it, can't even delete things from there

**UPDATE**

I tried to install all those packages manually, tried Synaptic, tried whatever but when I tried to install a previous version of Warzone it said that a new one is installed. I tried to delete Warzone and can't do it, see screenshot. I'm confused now what to do with this game.

[Synaptic Warzone removal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfWqj.png)

Comment: 0) Did you download the `.deb` package for *Trusy Tahr*? Or the package for the lates ubuntu version? 1) `apt-get` is used to install packages from repositories so the answer is yuo don't. 2) Replace `/path/to/deb/file` with the full path of the `.deb` file. If your username is `bob` and you downloaded the `file.deb` into your `Dowloads` folder the path will look like `/home/bob/Downloads/file.deb`. 3) Why do you want to do that? In any case: you can't due to *permissions*. Guess which tool Ubuntu uses to let you run commands with higher permissions?

Comment: Just try to install warzone 2100 on ubuntu 14.04 and tell me how to do it. It's impossible because of the dependencies

Comment: Go to the [launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/warzone2100). If you scroll down you see that it lists various **different** ubuntu versions and their specific package. Did you download the one *specific* for Trusty Tahr? (i.e. [this one](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/warzone2100/3.1~rc2-1ubuntu3)) If you are using one for a different version you should *expect* such dependency errors.

Comment: So it depends on the initial Ubuntu version? Other Ubuntu of the same 14.04 edition may have different packages? Then how do I install all those packages? I tried manually but they still appear in the dependencies list

Comment: 1) You still haven't answered my question. 2) There is no such thing as "initial Ubuntu version". There is only one version on your system. You stated that you are using ubuntu 14.04 (i.e. trusty tahr). then you have to install the packages for that version.

Comment: Do you know the answer on the particular question about Warzone dependencies and how to install them properly? it's about the correct way to install packages, not about Ubuntu version

Comment: One possible answer, as I mentioned: you are installing the package for the wrong version which obviously depends on packages that do not exist in your version of ubuntu. That's exactly the difference that there is between the package for warzone2100 for different ubuntu versions: they depend on different packages. If you try to install warzone2100 for Ubuntu 16.04 on ubuntu 14.04 you **ought** to get the same kind of error you are receiving.

Comment: Now I got it, ok.